# Email not sending from php form

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, email

i've made a php form and I'm sure the code is 100% fine, but it won't send.

I have a vps running Linux, and I have apache and PHP installed on it.

Do I have to configure anything to let my server send mails using PHP? I've tried sending my mails to gmail and to my exchange mail with the same domain as my website I'm trying to send mails from.

I've tried everything on google, but all the tutorials just write the PHP code and it sends the email, but i get nothing.

The only thing in the log is:

> Oct 24 18:21:46 vps-2c012137 opendkim[17717]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 starting

```
    <?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'kontakt@vlfmedia.dk';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 
    
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: plz share the code which you have implemented. also do check your mail spam folder, usually the email are sent to spam folder when sent from server.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe The code should be on here.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I went over all that, but nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: @Hermansen Really? Did you not spot the big text that says **Check the mail() return value**? This is basic stuff.